# IGC file to CSV

Tags: java, csv, jakarta-ee

I am trying to write a java code, for the conversion of an IGC file which has its inputs as the Latitude, longitude, Altitude, and time, to a simple CSV file.
Unfortunately I have not been successful.
can anyone help me !

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you done? How did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPSBabel understands IGC files and can convert them to other formats--perhaps you can use this?
http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.4.2/fmt_igc.html

Comment: Somehow I am not looking for a software that does it, rather a hint, or a Java code of how to convert an igc file to a csv !

Answer (score 0):

JFlight has an IGC converter written in java and it's open source.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jflight/